# How to simplify an arithmetic expression tree with recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, tree

How would i use recursion to simplify an expression tree? For example:

[image]

I've tried a few different things but I cannot figure out how to recurse through the tree in a way that i am able to simplify it. Thanks.

```
public static LinkedBinaryTree<String> simplify(LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    if (!isArithmeticExpression(tree) || tree == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arithmetic expression or Tree is null");
    }

    return simplify(tree.root(), tree);
}

public static LinkedBinaryTree<String> simplify(Position<String> p, LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree) {
    //      if (tree.isExternal(p)) {
    //          return tree;
    //      }
    if (isAlphaNumeric(p.getElement())) {

    }

    if (p.getElement().equals("+") || p.getElement().equals("+") || p.getElement().equals("+")) {

    }

    String element = p.getElement();
    char charLeft = tree.left(p).getElement().charAt(0);
    char charRight = tree.right(p).getElement().charAt(0);
    String stringLeft = tree.left(p).getElement();
    String stringRight = tree.right(p).getElement();

    //      if (stringLeft.equals("+") || stringLeft.equals("-") || stringLeft.equals("*")) {
    //          simplify(tree.left(p), tree);
    //      }

    //      if (!(Character.isLetter(charLeft) || Character.isDigit(charLeft))) {
    //          
    //      }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example, but you can adapt it further to your needs:

```
int simplify(Node root) {

    if(root == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int result;

    switch (root.value) {
        case "-":
            result = simplify(root.left) - simplify(root.right);
            break;
        case "+":
            result = simplify(root.left) + simplify(root.right);
            break;
        default:
            return Integer.parseInt(root.value);

    }
    return result;
}
```

So the idea is to go through your `tree`, you can have two case here:

- node's value is an operand, in that case you recursively go to the right and left node while applying the given operand.
- node's value is number, then you just return it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code which will put you in the right direction!

```
public int calculate() {
    return calculateNode(rootNode)
}

private int calculateNode(Node node) {
    if (node.isOperator()){
        int operandLeft = calculateNode(node.leftChild();
        int operandRight = calculateNode(node.leftChild();
        return node.getOperator().operateOn(operandLeft, operandRight);
    } else {
        return node.getValue()      
    }
}
```

The function `calculate()` is meant to be a function on the entire tree which sets of the recursion.

And the important thing with the recursive function `calculateNode(Node node)` is to see the end condition of when-a-node-is-a-number but it can also be tricky sometimes to realise that the recursive function should call itself twice in a single call so to speak.